# IBM Worklight - Error while trying to deploy application/adapter

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-studio, worklight-adapters

I have created a database using the Phpmyadmin (xampp server).

> Database name = 'database'
>  Username = 'user'

Password is empty. When I tried to change the worklight.properties file, it says some 
Poolable connection error:

> [ERROR   ] SRVE0315E: An execption occurred:
>   com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebAppErrorReport:
>   javax.servlet.ServletException: Worklight Project not initialized     at
>   com.worklight.core.auth.impl.AuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AuthenticationFilter.java:110)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:194)
>     at [internal classes] Caused by: javax.servlet.ServletException:
>   Worklight Project not initialized     ... 4 more

And also whenever I invoke the adapter or deploy the application it shows:

> Application Error SRVE0777E: Exception thrown by application class
>   'com.worklight.core.auth.impl.AuthenticationFilter.doFilter:110' 
>   javax.servlet.ServletException: Worklight Project not initialized
>
> at
>   com.worklight.core.auth.impl.AuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AuthenticationFilter.java:110)
>   at
>   com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:194)
>   at [internal classes]

When I click on the com.worklight.core.auth.impl.AuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AuthenticationFilter.java:110) line it shows that there is a missing .jar file.

[image: it shows the some jar file missing.]

**worklight.properties**

```
wl.db.type=MYSQL 
wl.db.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/database
wl.reports.db.username=root
wl.reports.db.password=
```

**Adapter.xml**

```
<connectivity>
        <connectionPolicy xsi:type="sql:SQLConnectionPolicy">
            <!-- Example for using a JNDI data source, replace with actual data source name -->
            <!-- <dataSourceJNDIName>java:/data-source-jndi-name</dataSourceJNDIName> -->

            <!-- Example for using MySQL connector, do not forget to put the MySQL connector library in the project's lib folder -->
            <dataSourceDefinition>
                <driverClass>com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</driverClass>
                <url>jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/database</url>

                <user>root</user>
                <password></password> 

            </dataSourceDefinition>
        </connectionPolicy>
```

**adapter-impl.js**

```
var selectStatement = WL.Server.createSQLStatement("SELECT * FROM users;");

function getAuths() {

    return WL.Server.invokeSQLStoredProcedure({
        procedure : getAuths,
        parameters : []
    });
}
```

**Complete Error Message while deploying the application:**

```
    Launching worklight (WebSphere Application Server 8.5.5.0/wlp-1.0.3.20130524-0951) on Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM, version 1.7.0_25-b17 (en_US)
    [AUDIT   ] CWWKE0001I: The server worklight has been launched.
    [AUDIT   ] CWWKZ0058I: Monitoring dropins for applications. 
    [AUDIT   ] CWWKT0016I: Web application available (default_host): http://lpch2-ee206922.sasken.com:10080/WorklightStarter_jQueryMobile/
    [err] 261  WorklightPU  WARN   [Scheduled Executor-thread-1] openjpa.Runtime - An error occurred while registering a ClassTransformer with PersistenceUnitInfo: name 'WorklightPU', root URL [file:/C:/Users/ee206922/Documents/WorklightServerConfig/shared/resources/worklight-jee-library-6.0.0.jar]. The error has been consumed. To see it, set your openjpa.Runtime log level to TRACE. Load-time class transformation will not be available.
    [WARNING ] Using empty value for configuration property 'ssl.keystore.path'
    [WARNING ] Using empty value for configuration property 'ssl.keystore.password'
    [err] 4055  WorklightPU  INFO   [Scheduled Executor-thread-1] openjpa.Runtime - Starting OpenJPA 1.2.2
    [err] 4579  WorklightPU  INFO   [Scheduled Executor-thread-1] openjpa.jdbc.JDBC - Using dictionary class "org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.sql.HSQLDictionary".
    [err] 1  WorklightReportsPU  WARN   [Scheduled Executor-thread-1] openjpa.Runtime - An error occurred while registering a ClassTransformer with PersistenceUnitInfo: name 'WorklightReportsPU', root URL [file:/C:/Users/ee206922/Documents/WorklightServerConfig/shared/resources/worklight-jee-library-6.0.0.jar]. The error has been consumed. To see it, set your openjpa.Runtime log level to TRACE. Load-time class transformation will not be available.
    [AUDIT   ] CWWKZ0001I: Application WorklightStarter_jQueryMobile started in 24.574 seconds.
    [AUDIT   ] CWWKT0016I: Web application available (default_host): http://proxy-22.eksi.com:10080/ProjectKen2/
    [ERROR   ] FWLSE0188E: Failed to connect to MYSQL database : Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory (Access denied for user 'Worklight'@'localhost' (using password: YES)) [project ProjectKen2]
    [ERROR   ] FWLST0003E: ========= Failed starting project /ProjectKen2 [project ProjectKen2]
    Error creating bean with name 'txManager' defined in URL [wsjar:file:/C:/Users/ee206922/Documents/WorklightServerConfig/shared/resources/worklight-jee-library-6.0.0.jar!/conf/core.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'brokerSessionFactory' while setting bean property 'entityManagerFactory'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'brokerSessionFactory' defined in URL [wsjar:file:/C:/Users/ee206922/Documents/WorklightServerConfig/shared/resources/worklight-jee-library-6.0.0.jar!/conf/spring-server-core.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'rssBrokerDS' while setting bean property 'dataSource'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'rssBrokerDS' defined in URL [wsjar:file:/C:/Users/ee206922/Documents/WorklightServerConfig/shared/resources/worklight-jee-library-6.0.0.jar!/conf/spring-server-core.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'worklight-direct' while setting bean property 'targetDataSource'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'worklight-direct' defined in URL [wsjar:file:/C:/Users/ee206922/Documents/WorklightServerConfig/shared/resources/worklight-jee-library-6.0.0.jar!/conf/spring-server-core.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.apache.commons.dbcp.SQLNestedException: Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory (Access denied for user 'Worklight'@'localhost' (using password: YES))
    [ERROR   ] SRVE0283E: Exception caught while initializing context: java.lang.RuntimeException: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'txManager' defined in URL [wsjar:file:/C:/Users/ee206922/Documents/WorklightServerConfig/shared/resources/worklight-jee-library-6.0.0.jar!/conf/core.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'brokerSessionFactory' while setting bean property 'entityManagerFactory'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'brokerSessionFactory' defined in URL [wsjar:file:/C:/Users/ee206922/Documents/WorklightServerConfig/shared/resources/worklight-jee-library-6.0.0.jar!/conf/spring-server-core.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'rssBrokerDS' while setting bean property 'dataSource'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'rssBrokerDS' defined in URL [wsjar:file:/C:/Users/ee206922/Documents/WorklightServerConfig/shared/resources/worklight-jee-library-6.0.0.jar!/conf/spring-server-core.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'worklight-direct' while setting bean property 'targetDataSource'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'worklight-direct' defined in URL [wsjar:file:/C:/Users/ee206922/Documents/WorklightServerConfig/shared/resources/worklight-jee-library-6.0.0.jar!/conf/spring-server-core.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.apache.commons.dbcp.SQLNestedException: Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory (Access denied for user 'Worklight'@'localhost' (using password: YES))
        at com.worklight.server.bundle.project.JeeProjectActivator.contextInitialized(JeeProjectActivator.java:146)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.notifyServletContextCreated(WebApp.java:2220)
        at [internal classes]
    Caused by (repeated) ... : org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'txManager' defined in URL [wsjar:file:/C:/Users/ee206922/Documents/WorklightServerConfig/shared/resources/worklight-jee-library-6.0.0.jar!/conf/core.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'brokerSessionFactory' while setting bean property 'entityManagerFactory'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'brokerSessionFactory' defined in URL [wsjar:file:/C:/Users/ee206922/Documents/WorklightServerConfig/shared/resources/worklight-jee-library-6.0.0.jar!/conf/spring-server-core.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'rssBrokerDS' while setting bean property 'dataSource'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'rssBrokerDS' defined in URL [wsjar:file:/C:/Users/ee206922/Documents/WorklightServerConfig/shared/resources/worklight-jee-library-6.0.0.jar!/conf/spring-server-core.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'worklight-direct' while setting bean property 'targetDataSource'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'worklight-direct' defined in URL [wsjar:file:/C:/Users/ee206922/Documents/WorklightServerConfig/shared/resources/worklight-jee-library-6.0.0.jar!/conf/spring-server-core.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.apache.commons.dbcp.SQLNestedException: Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory (Access denied for user 'Worklight'@'localhost' (using password: YES))
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:275)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:104)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1245)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1010)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:472)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory$1.run(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:409)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:380)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:264)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:261)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:185)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:164)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:429)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:728)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:380)
        at com.worklight.server.bundle.project.JeeProjectActivator.loadSpringConfiguration(JeeProjectActivator.java:273)
        at com.worklight.server.bundle.project.JeeProjectActivator.contextInitialized(JeeProjectActivator.java:134)
        ... 2 more
    Caused by: org.apache.commons.dbcp.SQLNestedException: Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory (Access denied for user 'Worklight'@'localhost' (using password: YES))
        at org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.createPoolableConnectionFactory(BasicDataSource.java:1549)
        at org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.createDataSource(BasicDataSource.java:1388)
        at org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.getConnection(BasicDataSource.java:1044)
        at com.worklight.server.database.api.WorklightDataSource.getConnection(WorklightDataSource.java:234)
        at com.worklight.server.database.api.WorklightDataSource.afterPropertiesSet(WorklightDataSource.java:110)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1369)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1335)
        ... 55 more
    Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Access denied for user 'Worklight'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1078)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:4120)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:4052)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:925)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.proceedHandshakeWithPluggableAuthentication(MysqlIO.java:1704)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.doHandshake(MysqlIO.java:1250)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.coreConnect(ConnectionImpl.java:2483)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectOneTryOnly(ConnectionImpl.java:2516)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:2301)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:834)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection.<init>(JDBC4Connection.java:47)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:411)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:416)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:317)
        at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DriverConnectionFactory.createConnection(DriverConnectionFactory.java:38)
        at org.apache.commons.dbcp.PoolableConnectionFactory.makeObject(PoolableConnectionFactory.java:582)
        at org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.validateConnectionFactory(BasicDataSource.java:1556)
        at org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.createPoolableConnectionFactory(BasicDataSource.java:1545)
        ... 61 more

    [AUDIT   ] CWWKZ0001I: Application ProjectKen2 started in 1.638 seconds.

Launching worklight (WebSphere Application Server 8.5.5.0/wlp-1.0.3.20130524-0951) on Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM, version 1.7.0_25-b17 (en_US)
[AUDIT   ] CWWKE0001I: The server worklight has been launched.
[AUDIT   ] CWWKZ0058I: Monitoring dropins for applications. 
[AUDIT   ] CWWKT0016I: Web application available (default_host): http://lpch2-ee206922.sasken.com:10080/WorklightStarter_jQueryMobile/
[err] 261  WorklightPU  WARN   [Scheduled Executor-thread-1] openjpa.Runtime - An error occurred while registering a ClassTransformer with PersistenceUnitInfo: name 'WorklightPU', root URL [file:/C:/Users/ee206922/Documents/WorklightServerConfig/shared/resources/worklight-jee-library-6.0.0.jar]. The error has been consumed. To see it, set your openjpa.Runtime log level to TRACE. Load-time class transformation will not be available.
[WARNING ] Using empty value for configuration property 'ssl.keystore.path'
[WARNING ] Using empty value for configuration property 'ssl.keystore.password'
[err] 4055  WorklightPU  INFO   [Scheduled Executor-thread-1] openjpa.Runtime - Starting OpenJPA 1.2.2
[err] 4579  WorklightPU  INFO   [Scheduled Executor-thread-1] openjpa.jdbc.JDBC - Using dictionary class "org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.sql.HSQLDictionary".
[err] 1  WorklightReportsPU  WARN   [Scheduled Executor-thread-1] openjpa.Runtime - An error occurred while registering a ClassTransformer with PersistenceUnitInfo: name 'WorklightReportsPU', root URL [file:/C:/Users/ee206922/Documents/WorklightServerConfig/shared/resources/worklight-jee-library-6.0.0.jar]. The error has been consumed. To see it, set your openjpa.Runtime log level to TRACE. Load-time class transformation will not be available.
[AUDIT   ] CWWKZ0001I: Application WorklightStarter_jQueryMobile started in 24.574 seconds.
[AUDIT   ] CWWKT0016I: Web application available (default_host): http://proxy-22.eksi.com:10080/ProjectKen2/
[ERROR   ] FWLSE0188E: Failed to connect to MYSQL database : Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory (Access denied for user 'Worklight'@'localhost' (using password: YES)) [project ProjectKen2]
[ERROR   ] FWLST0003E: ========= Failed starting project /ProjectKen2 [project ProjectKen2]
Error creating bean with name 'txManager' defined in URL [wsjar:file:/C:/Users/ee206922/Documents/WorklightServerConfig/shared/resources/worklight-jee-library-6.0.0.jar!/conf/core.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'brokerSessionFactory' while setting bean property 'entityManagerFactory'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'brokerSessionFactory' defined in URL [wsjar:file:/C:/Users/ee206922/Documents/WorklightServerConfig/shared/resources/worklight-jee-library-6.0.0.jar!/conf/spring-server-core.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'rssBrokerDS' while setting bean property 'dataSource'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'rssBrokerDS' defined in URL [wsjar:file:/C:/Users/ee206922/Documents/WorklightServerConfig/shared/resources/worklight-jee-library-6.0.0.jar!/conf/spring-server-core.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'worklight-direct' while setting bean property 'targetDataSource'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'worklight-direct' defined in URL [wsjar:file:/C:/Users/ee206922/Documents/WorklightServerConfig/shared/resources/worklight-jee-library-6.0.0.jar!/conf/spring-server-core.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.apache.commons.dbcp.SQLNestedException: Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory (Access denied for user 'Worklight'@'localhost' (using password: YES))
[ERROR   ] SRVE0283E: Exception caught while initializing context: java.lang.RuntimeException: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'txManager' defined in URL [wsjar:file:/C:/Users/ee206922/Documents/WorklightServerConfig/shared/resources/worklight-jee-library-6.0.0.jar!/conf/core.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'brokerSessionFactory' while setting bean property 'entityManagerFactory'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'brokerSessionFactory' defined in URL [wsjar:file:/C:/Users/ee206922/Documents/WorklightServerConfig/shared/resources/worklight-jee-library-6.0.0.jar!/conf/spring-server-core.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'rssBrokerDS' while setting bean property 'dataSource'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'rssBrokerDS' defined in URL [wsjar:file:/C:/Users/ee206922/Documents/WorklightServerConfig/shared/resources/worklight-jee-library-6.0.0.jar!/conf/spring-server-core.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'worklight-direct' while setting bean property 'targetDataSource'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'worklight-direct' defined in URL [wsjar:file:/C:/Users/ee206922/Documents/WorklightServerConfig/shared/resources/worklight-jee-library-6.0.0.jar!/conf/spring-server-core.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.apache.commons.dbcp.SQLNestedException: Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory (Access denied for user 'Worklight'@'localhost' (using password: YES))
    at com.worklight.server.bundle.project.JeeProjectActivator.contextInitialized(JeeProjectActivator.java:146)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.notifyServletContextCreated(WebApp.java:2220)
    at [internal classes]
Caused by (repeated) ... : org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'txManager' defined in URL [wsjar:file:/C:/Users/ee206922/Documents/WorklightServerConfig/shared/resources/worklight-jee-library-6.0.0.jar!/conf/core.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'brokerSessionFactory' while setting bean property 'entityManagerFactory'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'brokerSessionFactory' defined in URL [wsjar:file:/C:/Users/ee206922/Documents/WorklightServerConfig/shared/resources/worklight-jee-library-6.0.0.jar!/conf/spring-server-core.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'rssBrokerDS' while setting bean property 'dataSource'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'rssBrokerDS' defined in URL [wsjar:file:/C:/Users/ee206922/Documents/WorklightServerConfig/shared/resources/worklight-jee-library-6.0.0.jar!/conf/spring-server-core.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'worklight-direct' while setting bean property 'targetDataSource'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'worklight-direct' defined in URL [wsjar:file:/C:/Users/ee206922/Documents/WorklightServerConfig/shared/resources/worklight-jee-library-6.0.0.jar!/conf/spring-server-core.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.apache.commons.dbcp.SQLNestedException: Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory (Access denied for user 'Worklight'@'localhost' (using password: YES))
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:275)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:104)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1245)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1010)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:472)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory$1.run(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:409)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:380)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:264)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:261)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:185)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:164)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:429)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:728)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:380)
    at com.worklight.server.bundle.project.JeeProjectActivator.loadSpringConfiguration(JeeProjectActivator.java:273)
    at com.worklight.server.bundle.project.JeeProjectActivator.contextInitialized(JeeProjectActivator.java:134)
    ... 2 more
Caused by: org.apache.commons.dbcp.SQLNestedException: Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory (Access denied for user 'Worklight'@'localhost' (using password: YES))
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.createPoolableConnectionFactory(BasicDataSource.java:1549)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.createDataSource(BasicDataSource.java:1388)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.getConnection(BasicDataSource.java:1044)
    at com.worklight.server.database.api.WorklightDataSource.getConnection(WorklightDataSource.java:234)
    at com.worklight.server.database.api.WorklightDataSource.afterPropertiesSet(WorklightDataSource.java:110)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1369)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1335)
    ... 55 more
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Access denied for user 'Worklight'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1078)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:4120)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:4052)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:925)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.proceedHandshakeWithPluggableAuthentication(MysqlIO.java:1704)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.doHandshake(MysqlIO.java:1250)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.coreConnect(ConnectionImpl.java:2483)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectOneTryOnly(ConnectionImpl.java:2516)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:2301)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:834)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection.<init>(JDBC4Connection.java:47)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:411)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:416)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:317)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DriverConnectionFactory.createConnection(DriverConnectionFactory.java:38)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.PoolableConnectionFactory.makeObject(PoolableConnectionFactory.java:582)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.validateConnectionFactory(BasicDataSource.java:1556)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.createPoolableConnectionFactory(BasicDataSource.java:1545)
    ... 61 more

[AUDIT   ] CWWKZ0001I: Application ProjectKen2 started in 1.638 seconds.
```

Comment: You see in your error log where it is saying "Caused by: ... Worklight Project not initialized"? If you scroll up just a little bit more, there should be a longer error message also in red (you may need to scroll to the right quite a bit to get the whole message). Can you paste what that message says?

Comment: Pls check the updated Question, jeremy. Still struggling with this.. it basically has three 'caused by' 1. Caused by (repeated) ... : org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: 2. Caused by: org.apache.commons.dbcp.SQLNestedException: Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory (Access denied for user 'Worklight'@'localhost' (using password: YES)) 3. Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Access denied for user 'Worklight'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be clear: the database you have created, what is it meant for? Is it meant to be the database for Worklight Server, or is it meant to be a backend for some service for your adapter to connect to?

- If it is not meant for Worklight Server, but rather is some backend, don't touch worklight.properties.
- Otherwise, edit the question and explain that part.

Please also go over [IBM Worklight Getting Started](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/mobile/worklight/getting-started.html#server-side-development) and [this training module](http://public.dhe.ibm.com/software/mobile-solutions/worklight/docs/v600/04_03_SQL_adapter_-_Communicating_with_SQL_database.pdf) ([sample app](http://public.dhe.ibm.com/software/mobile-solutions/worklight/docs/v600/WorklightAdaptersProject.zip)), to familiarize yourself with the various concepts and options in Worklight.

Finally, see if the following help:

1. Make sure the username and password values you've entered in worklight.properties are correct

   - Your quote of worklight.properties only shows the reports database username and password, and not those of Worklight Server - this only after my question above
   - Why do you add username/pasword to the reports database? Did you create a database for reports? I feel that you need to go over the training modules.
2. Make sure the MySQL JDBC Connector/J driver .jar file is located in yourProject\server\lib
3. In your database, make sure the user Worklight@% and/or Worklight@localhost have full permission on the database you've created

Verify all three are OK in your project and environment.

Comment: Thank you very much Idan. I have removed all the things I have entered in the worklight.properties file and deployed the adapter. still got some json function error. Then changed WL.Server.invokeSQLStoredProcedure to WL.Server.invokeSQLStatement it has started to work Perfectly. I am hoping to find some documents regarding when should we make an entry to the worklight.properties.

Comment: Read all the Getting Started material from start-to-end; educate yourself about Worklight, that's the only REAL way.

Answer (score 1):

```
 Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Access denied for user 'Worklight'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
```

So it looks like worklight is getting to your database but either your username or password is incorrrect.

Could this be your problem:

```
wl.db.type=MYSQL 
wl.db.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/database
wl.reports.db.username=root
wl.reports.db.password=
```

You seem to be setting the wl.**reports**.db.username and wl.**reports**.db.password

Are you using the reports database? Did you mean to set the following:

```
wl.db.username=user
wl.db.password=
```

Answer (score 0):

I was getting the same error.
When I created the data base user , I used wild cards to grant permissions i.e. "%" for any host and "*" for all data bases.
Later I gave very specific credentials, I created the same user again and granted all permissions for that user on local host for the specific database that I wish to connect to.
I redeployed the adapter and invoked it again successfully without any errors